# How to make responsive links on the image

Tags: html, css, responsive

I added some links on the image, but when I resize the page the links are moving from their places. Any help to make them responsive, so they'll work with any width of the page ??

image : [image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1bRk.png)

html code :

```
<div>
    <img class="mainpage" src="img/landing.jpg" alt="Clup World" />
    <a href="#" title="signup" class="signup_link"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Egypt" class="eg_link"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Saudi Arabia" class="ksa_link"></a>
    <a href="#" title="United Arab Emirates" class="uae_link"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Bahrain" class="bh_link"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Qatar" class="qa_link"></a>
</div>
```

css code :

```
    body
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin:0;
    }
    .mainpage {
        max-width:100% !important;
        max-height:100% !important;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:fixed; 
    }
    .signup_link {
        width:204px;
        height:62px;
        position:absolute;  
        display: block;
        right:17px;
        top:20px;
        border-style: dashed;
    }
.eg_link {
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;  
    display: block;
    left:515px;
    bottom:60px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.ksa_link {
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;  
    display: block;
    left:595px;
    bottom:60px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.uae_link {
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;  
    display: block;
    left:678px;
    bottom:60px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.bh_link {
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;  
    display: block;
    left:763px;
    bottom:60px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.qa_link {
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;  
    display: block;
    left:848px;
    bottom:60px;
    border-style: dashed;
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just wrap the link around the image? That way you wouldn't have to use position absolute, and try and make an "overlay"?  Example: `<a href="#"><img .... ></a>`...

Comment: the problem is the `width:100%; height:100%;` on the `.mainpage` have you tried using a fixed with and height?

Comment: For the most consistent results that button should really be a stand-alone element, sitting above the image, and not part of the image.

Comment: @cale_b , if you mean i put the link on all the image , No becouse there is another links i want to put them on same image

Comment: Show what you mean by that.  How do you "put other links" on the same image?

Comment: @MariusBrits , if i remove height,width from the class - the image not be take a full of page

Comment: @cale_b i edited my code , see it now

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError the links already not part of the image and they have alone element

Comment: How do you determine which link is "active"?

Comment: @user3745594 I'm referring to the button you are trying to map that link to, not the links itself - that button shouldn't be part of the image, rather a separate element positioned above the image, e.g: `<a href="#" title="signup" class="signup_link">Sign Up</a>`. Style your button to appear in the way you need it, rather than trying to map or position the link with absolute values over that part of the image.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError , when i put the link above the image , the link not active

Comment: @user3745594 Give it a higher `z-index` or position it `relative`. Then, have that image render through a `background-image` style rule instead, since that is how you are trying to use after all.

Comment: @cale_b , i cannot understand your question .. sorry , i want all this links to be active on same image

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError , can you gave me a small Example to understand what you mean .

Comment: Sorry, yes - got it.  It's like an image map, yes? Different parts of the image are clickable.  You need to do two things: 1. change the image from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` (or relative), and 2. Change all of your link `top, left, width, height` values to percentages.

Comment: @user3745594 have a look at this fiddle to get an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/zdc1s66L/3/ For the best results combine the html markup and styles (remembering to inline the styles in `<style>` tags, placing it above the html), add `data:text/html,` before all the markup and styles, copy everything, paste it in your browser address bar and hit enter.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError , i try with your code and it is same problem - links are moving from there places when i resize the page :(

Comment: @cale_b , thanks .. i do that but it is same problem when i resize the page https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1bRk.png

Comment: Have you tried making your web page size fixed to exactly the size of your background image, this will cause scrolling issues etc. Personally I would have a background image and assign an image to each link and then this could adapt to any size page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try giving `width:100%; height:auto` for images to make them responsive.
2. you can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and then use `class="img-responsive"`within img tag.